# How can I change the object a pointer points to after this pointer used a function

Tags: c++, pointers

```
Object *a;

Object c;

Object b;

a = &b;

a-> function();
```

Before the pointer `'a'` use this function, it points to object `'b'`. How can I make it point to object 'c' after this function is used.

Comment: `a` is pointing to `c` before the calling the `function` itself.

Comment: Sorry, I mean a=&b at first. Then I want to change 'a' to points to 'c'

Comment: Just assign it after calling the function as you do now before the function call.

Comment: And what is the problem, just write `a = &c` and `a` now points to `c`

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. Here is a pointer points to a object 'b'. Then, I use a->function(). After that, I can make this pointer point to object 'c'. I want to make this change in this function. How can I do that?

Comment: @SYY that's not possible with the syntax you have : `a` will be `this` in the function, which is `const`.

Comment: It is this function to change b to c the pointer points to

Comment: This is an XY problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're okay with passing a couple of arguments to `function()`, you could always implement it like this:

```
void Object::function(Object* pObject, Object& rObject) {
    pObject = &rObject;
}
```

And in working code, use it like this:

```
Object *a;

Object c;

Object b;

a = &b;              //'a' is pointing to 'b'

a->function(a, c);   //'a' is now pointing to 'c'
```

In a practical sense, though, you're still much better off using this:

```
a = &c;
```